# Rounded screen corners throughout the app with status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwindow

How can I achieve rounded corners on the screen while still displaying the status bar?

In the application delegate I am applying these settings to the window:

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.window.layer.opaque = NO;
```

but at the top of the screen I am not seeing the rounded corner because of the status bar. This is a problem because I need the status bar in the app too.

Can anyone suggest how I may fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to remove the status bar? Or are you trying to round the corners of the status bar? If you are wanting to round the corners of the status bar, the quick and simple answer is that you cannot. If you want to remove the status bar, this is quick and easy:

**From Apple Class Reference:**

> **setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:**
>
> Hides or shows the status bar, optionally animating the transition. -
>   `(void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden
>   withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation Parameters`
>
> hidden YES to hide the status bar, NO to show the status bar.
>
> animation A constant that indicates whether there should be an
>   animation and, if one is requested, whether it should fade the status
>   bar in or out or whether it should slide the status bar in or out.

Comment: I dont want to remove the status bar. After the status bar when the view starts i need rounded corners.

Comment: some thing like this bounded content - http://blog.edwardmarks.com/post/9859783254/improve-usability-with-a-black-status-bar-and-rounded

Comment: You don't need to round your window then as I believe that includes the status bar. You need to round your controllers base views. such as navigationController.view or rootViewController.view

Comment: Also you need to consider that if you're using a standard status bar the corners SHOULD NOT be rounded below it as it leaves gaps that are displeasing and confusing to the user. However if you simple set your status bar black this is no longer a problem. Thats why all iPad status bars start as black because all apps start with rounded corners.

Comment: Ya thanks i am seeing the rounded corners. But i am setting the status bar as black and the cut space of rounded corners are not black. So how can i make it to black?

Comment: the default background for all views and windows should be black. but somehow in your case I'm guessing not. Just set the background on your rootViews to black and I believe that would fix it.

Comment: Absolutely rite app window was not black.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the status bar and still see the rounded edges, you'll have to round the edges of the view instead of the window.

In which case, you're code would be almost identical but applied to the view instead:

```
[self.view.layer setCornerRadius:10.0];
[self.view.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
self.view.layer.opaque = NO;
```

This would go in the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in the `viewWillAppear` method. It will give a rounded lookNfeel for the view. For this include the 'QuartzCore` framework.

```
self.view.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
```

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but just put

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    window?.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    window?.clipsToBounds = true
    window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

in your AppDelegate.swift and you have rounded corners everywhere in your app :D